# Join and Count Records SQL vba access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, join, count

i just started learning sql and i have a vba funtion that i want to convert to a simple sql. i have 4 tables that need to be joined then i need a total count where date>date1 & date < date2 and status= status_string and county=countyname (date1, date2, status_string, county names are variables).

```
SELECT COUNT(*), table1.date, table2.status, table3.county
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table1 ON table1.status=table2.staus
INNER JOIN table1 ON table1.cust_id=table3.cust_id 
INNER JOIN table3 ON table3.countyid=table4.countyname 
WHERE table4.status = Status_string and [table1.Date] > date_varaible_1 and [table1.Date] < date_varaible_2 and [table.county]=countyname
```

any help to correct this would be great.

ty

Comment: You may just be missing a `GROUP BY` clause but are you sure table 3's county id matches table 4's county name? Seems inconsistent.

Comment: Yea, i just named them differently. I would rename it but it would require alot of rewriting code.

Comment: How would i include the group by clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several things need adjustments in your query:

1. `JOIN` statements are not correct as you are joining *Table1* to itself multiple times (which is allowed for self-joins) but you then refer to *Table2*, *Table3*, and *Table4* which do not exist. Simply join by those tables. Possibly, these were simple typos.
2. MS Access SQL requires parentheses around table join pairings.
3. Brackets must wrap around a table name or field name. Two brackets cannot wrap both though two sets of brackets can be used: `[table].[field]`.
4. Add a `GROUP BY` at the end of query. In SQL, all non-aggregated (or unit-level) columns in `SELECT` of an aggregate query are considered the groupings and hence must be declared in a `GROUP BY`.
5. Consider a `BETWEEN` clause for your date range as recommended with [Query Performance Tips](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd942824(v=office.12).aspx#Anchor_4):

   > Between lets the search engine look for values in one evaluation
   >   rather than two

**SQL** Query adjustment

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*), table1.date, table2.status, table3.county
FROM ((table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.status = table2.staus)
INNER JOIN table3 ON table1.cust_id = table3.cust_id) 
INNER JOIN table4 ON table3.countyid = table4.countyname 
WHERE table1.[Date] BETWEEN date_variable_1 AND date_variable_2 
  AND table3.[county] = countyname
  AND table4.[status] = Status_string 
GROUP BY table1.date, table2.status, table3.county
```